# Django how to compare correctly against django.utils.timezone.localtime and PostgreSQL time with time zone?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-timezone

I have a legacy PostgreSQL table with `time with time zone` column.

in models.py I have the filed set to `models.TimeField`

I want to compare accessed `Django.utils.timezone.localtime()` with `db_field_time_with_time_zone`

I have tried below:

```
# let's say now=20:00 and db_field_time_with_time_zone=16:00
now = timezone.localtime()
data = timezone.datetime.combine(timezone.localdate(), db_field_time_with_time_zone)
self.assertTrue(now > data) # I get False...
```

In the raw PostgreSQL column it's stored as `16:00:00+09:00`
but when I retrieve data using `python manage.py shell` it returns `16:00:00+00:00` and I also think this is the cause of this problem.

In my settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'
USE_TZ = True
```